# disable this jQuery script for mobile devices with user agent?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, mobile, user-agent

I would like to disable part of my jQuery script for mobile devices, I came across this statement(Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test) but i have no clue of how to use it to disable part of my script for mobile devices, heres the code I'd like to disable, i want to remove the addClass FROM mobile devices, is for a navigation. im a noobie please help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 40) 
        { $('#container-wrapper-ab').addClass('container-wrapper-ab-fixed'); 
        } 
        else { $('#container-wrapper-ab').removeClass('container-wrapper-ab-fixed'); 
       } 


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the viewport size instead of useragent.

Since you are using jQuery, you can just check it with

```
$(window).width()
```

Comment: i am creating a responsive website, for the desktop id like to keep the script on, but for mobiles i want to remove the class?

Comment: So, you would compare $(window).width() to your responsive breakpoint(s).